# String manipulation c#

Tags: c#, string, linq

I got a string like, `A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:<<Default>>`[template string]

The representation of string is like dictionary key:Value which is grouped as string with semicolon separator.

Now after applying logics, I get a list of strings below,

```
A:aaa;E:eee
D:ddd
B:bbb;E:eee
```

Now I need make the above list as one below (where the key with new value should be placed in the right order and having the remaining keys with default values),

```
A:aaa;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee
A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:ddd;E:<<Default>>
A:<<Default>>;B:bbb;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee
```

Tried with split function, Replace and converting to list to achieve this. Do we have any effective way to achieve the same?

```
string constants = "A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:<<Default>>";
            string placeHolder = string.Empty;


            List<string> filteredkeys = new List<string>();
            List<string> formattedKeys = new List<string>();
            filteredkeys.Add("A:aaa;E:eee;");
            filteredkeys.Add("D:ddd;");
            filteredkeys.Add("B:bbb;E:eee;");

            foreach (var item in filteredkeys)
            {
                placeHolder = constants;
                List<string> keyCombination = item.TrimEnd(';').Split(';').ToList();
                foreach (string keys in keyCombination)
                {
                    List<string> abc = keys.Split(':').ToList();
                    switch (abc[0])
                    {
                        case "A":
                            placeHolder = placeHolder.Replace("A:<<Default>>", keys);
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            placeHolder = placeHolder.Replace("B:<<Default>>", keys);
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            placeHolder = placeHolder.Replace("C:<<Default>>", keys);
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            placeHolder = placeHolder.Replace("D:<<Default>>", keys);
                            break;
                        case "E":
                            placeHolder = placeHolder.Replace("D:<<Default>>", keys);
                            break;
                    }                    
                }
                formattedKeys.Add(placeHolder);
            }
```

Comment: What .NET are you using (3.5, 4, 4.5...)?

Comment: what was wrong with Split?

Comment: @fubo updated with piece of code tried with foreach & Switch case. Thanks for looking in to this :)

Comment: @Dialecticus, Am using .NET4.5 Thanks for looking in to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Linq* solution:

```
  String source = @"A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:<<Default>>";

  // Note, that "E" value (eee:fff:ggg:hhh) contains semicolons
  String values = "A:aaa;E:eee:fff:ggg:hhh";  

  var dict = values
    .Split(';')
    .Select(item => item.Split(new Char[] {':'}, 2)) // "2": if value contains ':'
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk[0], chunk => chunk[1]);

  String result = String.Join(";", source
    .Split(';')
    .Select(item => item.Split(':'))
    .Select(item => String.Join(":", 
       item[0],
       dict.ContainsKey(item[0]) ? dict[item[0]] : item[1])));

  // Test
  // A:aaa;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee:fff:ggg:hhh
  Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: missed to mention this, the value string might contain character ':' when the value is DataTime value for example. Anyhow thanks a lot to make my code more simpler usin above linq. Will try with this.

Comment: @Programming: a small modification (see my edit) will solve the task: `new Char[] {':'}, 2)` when creating dictionary

Answer (score 1):

This is a very straight-forward solution that simply parses the string, and then applies the elements to the dictionary you pass. In order to use the template string, you simply apply the template string *first*, and then apply the actual string you want to process overwriting all default values if appropriate:

```
public void ParseAndApply(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string text)
{
    foreach (string element in text.Split(';'))
    {
        string[] parts = element.Split(new char[]{ ':' }, 2);
        dictionary[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    }
}

public string ConvertToString(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    return string.Join(";", dictionary.Select(kv => kv.Key + ":" + kv.Value));
}
```

Used like this:

```
string[] strings = { "A:aaa;E:eee", "D:ddd", "B:bbb;E:eee" };

foreach (string exampleString in strings)
{
    // create dictionary
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // apply from template string
    string templateString = "A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:<<Default>>";
    ParseAndApply(dict, templateString);

    // apply example string
    ParseAndApply(dict, exampleString);

    // write output
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(dict));
}
```

```
A:aaa;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee
A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:ddd;E:<<Default>>
A:<<Default>>;B:bbb;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee
```

---

> Missed to mention this, the value string might contain character ':' when the value is DataTime value for example

This wouldn’t be a problem with this solution as long as the *key* does not contain a colon. The way we split the element in `ParseAndApply`, we only perform the split once for the very first colon in it, so additional colons appearing later in the value are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with a passing unit test,

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var template = "A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:<<Default>>";

    Assert.AreEqual(Pair.Process("A:aaa;E:eee", template),
        "A:aaa;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee");

    Assert.AreEqual(Pair.Process("D:ddd", template),
        "A:<<Default>>;B:<<Default>>;C:<<Default>>;D:ddd;E:<<Default>>");

    Assert.AreEqual(Pair.Process("B:bbb;E:eee", template),
        "A:<<Default>>;B:bbb;C:<<Default>>;D:<<Default>>;E:eee");

}

public class Pair
{
    public static char InnerSeperator = ':';
    public static char OuterSeperator = ';';
    public static string DefaultValue = "<<Default>>";

    public Pair(string asString)
    {
        var strings = asString.Split(InnerSeperator).ToList();
        Key = strings[0];
        Value = strings.Count > 1 ? strings[1] : DefaultValue;
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Key, InnerSeperator, Value);
    }

    public static string ToStringJoined(IEnumerable<Pair> pairs)
    {
        return string.Join(OuterSeperator.ToString(), pairs.Select(i => i.ToString()));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Pair> FromJoinedString(string joined)
    {
        return joined.Split(OuterSeperator)
            .Select(x => x.Trim())
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
            .Select(x => new Pair(x));
    }

    public static string Process(string values, string template)
    {
        var templateItems = FromJoinedString(template);
        var valueItems = FromJoinedString(values);
        var resultItems = templateItems.Select(t => valueItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == t.Key) ?? t);
        return ToStringJoined(resultItems);
    }
}
```

cheers to life..